# ArrayList duplicate

Tags: java

> Consider a text file of IDs, with one ID per line, which has duplicate
>   IDs. We would like to eliminate the duplicate IDs by using an
>   ArrayList. Read each ID from the file, add it to the ArrayList if it
>   is not already added, and then output all IDs in the ArrayList to a
>   new text file..

i solved it that i will add all the id and then cheek if they exist and remove them however my doctor did not want them to  be add in the first place

```
 ArrayList<Integer> myid = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     int idset,count=14;

     while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
         idset = sc.nextInt();
         myid.add(idset);
     }
     for (int i = 1; i < myid.size(); i++) {
         int a1 = (int) myid.get(i);
         int a2 = (int) myid.get(i-1);
         if (a1 != a2) {
             count--;
         }
             else {
                 myid.remove(a1);
             }
     }
     pw.println(myid);
     pw.println("duplicate = "+count);
```

Comment: ehm ... ok? usually, my doctor just tells me whether I'm healthy or not. That being said: do you have a question?

Comment: use a Set - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html. Example: https://www.baeldung.com/convert-list-to-set-and-set-to-list

Comment: Yep, Just use a Set instead and tell your Doctor to chill.

Comment: Did you mean: *professor*?

Comment: sorry its normal in my native langue to call professor doctor

Comment: @adi7 it sounds funny because we also call professor's doctors, but you wouldn't use the possessive. ie. Doctor Foo is my professor. When you use the My Doctor implies your medical doctor and not your professor.

Answer (score 1):

So, the requirements didn't ask you to count anything... Not sure where `count=14` comes from.

> did not want them to be add in the first place

Then don't add them

Use **[`List#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)**

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
     idset = sc.nextInt();
     if (!myid.contains(idset)) { // <--- here
         myid.add(idset);
     }
 }
 myid.foreach(pw::println);
```

Note: The above code has `O(n^2)` runtime complexity, and `Set<Integer>` is more appropriate for this question, which has a runtime of `O(n)`, for the set of `n` ids.

And you could just make `new ArrayList<>(set)` to return a list, if you really wanted one

Answer (score 0):

```
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
    idset = sc.nextInt();
    if (!myid.contains(id)) {
        myid.add(idset);
    }
}
```

use the ArrayList.contains method